Should I prepare to Apple renewal of APNs USERTrust RSA Certification Authority certificate?
On apple dev site in the news section here you can find two announcements about their renewal of:

USERTrust RSA Certification Authority certificate.

now, I have an app delivered via in-house distribution due to Apple developer Enterprise program. My app uses push notifications, but we are using auth tokens.

Should I do something on the app?
Should I advice backend colleague to check or do something server-side?

below the two announcements:
sanbox link

APNs Certificate Update Begins January 20, 2025 The Apple Push
Notification service (APNs) will be updated with a new server
certificate in sandbox on January 20, 2025. Update your application’s
Trust Store to include the new server certificate: SHA-2 Root :
USERTrust RSA Certification Authority certificate.

and
production link

APNs Certificate Update Begins February 24, 2025 The Apple Push
Notification service (APNs) will be updated with a new server
certificate in production on February 24, 2025. Update your
application’s Trust Store to include the new server certificate: SHA-2
Root : USERTrust RSA Certification Authority certificate.


In case your push server is on a Linux server (e.g. CentOS, Debian), written using PHP and using the PHP curl library (or any other language platform which is using the system's truststore) OR you are using curl command for the purpose, you may download the new server certificate and place in the path:
CentOS location:
/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/

Debian location:
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates

then run the following command to update your system's trust store
CentOS: update-ca-trust

Debian: update-ca-certificates

Ref: How to add Certificate Authority file in CentOS 7
Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ca-certificate-management
In case you want to get your curl's CA truststore file / path, run this command to check, e.g.:
curl -v https://google.com

Then find the line start by: "*  CAfile: ..." or "*  CApath: ..."
Ref: https://serverfault.com/a/878229

From an Apple engineer here:

What specifically needs to be done to install the new certificate to the Trust store will be different for all kinds of OSs and may also be different based on the push application you are using. This is something your server admins will know and should be able to check and configure as necessary.


so, in your opinion, is the the answer a real full stack iOS developer should answer? (I'm not cmpletely "full stack anyway" but working to become one) something like "is out the scope of my job as iOS developer?"
