Apple Push Notification service server certificate update 2025
Certification Authority (CA) for Apple Push Notification service (APNs) is changing.
We are using firebase for push notification. As far I know we dont have to update server certificate and Seems like the Firebase team will update the server certificate on their end but I ant to know that as i am using both Apn certificate for one my firebase project and apn auth key another firebase project.Will this update of apple anyway affect that? do i need to do anything from my end?

Hi @Liza Routray
this question is already being asked, please refer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79184941/should-i-prepare-to-apple-renewal-of-apns-usertrust-rsa-certification-authority

but i need to know if i need to change anything with my apn auth key and apn ssl certificate

Citing from https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09za8wzy "At this time, you don’t need to update the APNs SSL provider certificates issued to you by Apple"

The upcoming changes to the Apple Push Notification service (APNs) server certificates, including the SHA-2 Root: USERTrust RSA Certification Authority update, will not directly impact developers using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push notifications. Firebase, as a third-party provider, will handle the necessary updates to its server certificates.
Apple's Official Statement:
From the Apple Developer :
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/770316
Forums:
This certificate update is only needed for developers who are running their own push servers to directly communicate with APNs. 3rd party push providers will need to handle this certificate update on their end.
Recommendation:
No additional action is required from your side. Firebase will automatically handle the changes to APNs certificates. For peace of mind, you can review Firebase’s documentation or contact Firebase Support if needed.

I just want to confirm -- will this affect PKS12 push certificates? I have a backend server that is using PKS12 certificates issued by Apple to send push notifications to APN

The PKS12 push certificates you use to authenticate with APNs will not be affected by this update. Apple explicitly stated in their announcement: "At this time, you don’t need to update the APNs SSL provider certificates issued to you by Apple." However, ensure your backend’s Trust Store includes the updated USERTrust RSA Certification Authority to maintain connectivity.
